# Revoke only Access Token, not Refresh Token

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

My application has access to my Google Drive through OAUTH2.

I use an admin panel to go through the flow and get the refresh token, then users of my application will generate access tokens using said refresh token in order to download one of my files.

All fine so far.

But I would like that these access tokens were revoked after used once, to avoid exploitations.

I tried using https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
But as the documentation says, this endpoint also revokes the Refresh Token... so each time a user downloads a file from my application, I would have to authenticate again to get a new refresh token.

How can I invalidate the access token (or issue a very short lived one) without revoking the refresh token? I searched extensively but couldn't find anything so far, and questions similar to this I found here on SO are unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a server application that has securely stored the Refresh Token and is using it to generate Access Tokens on demand. You have no control over the validity period of the Access Tokens.

What you can do is request an Access Token every minute and store them in a server-side cache. When a user needs an Access Token, give them one which is 59 minutes old (or more accurately, expiry time - 60 seconds).

Comment: That's brilliant, but at the same time lame... Google is such a giant, it's weird for them to not foresee such a situation.

Are there any limits on the amount of access tokens I can request?

Comment: it's fairly standard OAuth behaviour. The Access Token should be kept private in the user-browser so it's only a vulnerability if the user's device is compromised or left unattended. In that scenario it's no different from leaving a conventional session logged on. There is no limit on how many access tokens you can request.

Comment: When my application request an access token it's for the reason of downloading a file and he does that through a flow designed to invalidate the token after the request was made, this is to prevent the user from sharing the google drive authenticated download link.

But I guess your solution can work while my application is still small, so I will mark your answer.

Thank you very much

Comment: the only other approach I can think of would be for your server app to proxy the calls to GDrive so it can layer its own auth parameters.